# How to plot the Eigenvalues when solving matrix coupled differential equations in PYTHON?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, odeint

Lets say we have three complex matrices and a system of coupled differential equations with these matrices.

```
import numpy, scipy
from numpy import (real,imag,matrix,linspace,array)
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def system(x,t):

    a1= x[0];a3= x[1];a5= x[2];a7= x[3];
    a2= x[4];a4= x[5];a6= x[6];a8= x[7];
    b1= x[8];b3= x[9];b5= x[10];b7= x[11];
    b2= x[12];b4= x[13];b6= x[14];b8= x[15];
    c1= x[16];c3= x[17];c5= x[18];c7= x[19];
    c2= x[20];c4= x[21];c6= x[22];c8= x[23];

    A= matrix([ [a1+1j*a2,a3+1j*a4],[a5+1j*a6,a7+1j*a8] ])  
    B= matrix([ [b1+1j*b2,b3+1j*b4],[b5+1j*b6,b7+1j*b8] ])
    C= matrix([ [c1+1j*c2,c3+1j*c4],[c5+1j*c6,c7+1j*c8] ])

    dA_dt= A*C+B*C
    dB_dt= B*C
    dC_dt= C

    list_A_real= [dA_dt[0,0].real,dA_dt[0,1].real,dA_dt[1,0].real,dA_dt[1,1].real]
    list_A_imaginary= [dA_dt[0,0].imag,dA_dt[0,1].imag,dA_dt[1,0].imag,dA_dt[1,1].imag]

    list_B_real= [dB_dt[0,0].real,dB_dt[0,1].real,dB_dt[1,0].real,dB_dt[1,1].real]
    list_B_imaginary= [dB_dt[0,0].imag,dB_dt[0,1].imag,dB_dt[1,0].imag,dB_dt[1,1].imag]

    list_C_real= [dC_dt[0,0].real,dC_dt[0,1].real,dC_dt[1,0].real,dC_dt[1,1].real]
    list_C_imaginary= [dC_dt[0,0].imag,dC_dt[0,1].imag,dC_dt[1,0].imag,dC_dt[1,1].imag]

    return list_A_real+list_A_imaginary+list_B_real+list_B_imaginary+list_C_real+list_C_imaginary



t= linspace(0,1.5,1000)
A_initial= [1,2,2.3,4.3,2.1,5.2,2.13,3.43]
B_initial= [7,2.7,1.23,3.3,3.1,5.12,1.13,3]
C_initial= [0.5,0.9,0.63,0.43,0.21,0.5,0.11,0.3]
x_initial= array( A_initial+B_initial+C_initial )
x= odeint(system,x_initial,t)

plt.plot(t,x[:,0])
plt.show()
```

I have basically **two questions**:

1. **How to reduce my code?** By reduce I meant, is there a way to do this by not writing down all the components separately ,but handling with the matrices while solving the system of ODE?
2. Instead of plotting elements of the matrices with respect to **t** (the last 2 lines of my code), **how can I plot Eigenvalues (absolute values) (lets say, the abs of eigenvalues of matrix A as a function of t)?**

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct?  The line `a1= x[0];a2= x[1];a3= x[2];a4= x[3];...` combined with `A= matrix([ [a1+1j*a2,a3+1j*a4],...` says that the real and imaginary parts of `A` are interleaved in `x`, but when you assemble the return value of `system(x,t)`, you list all the real parts of `dA_dt`, followed by all the imaginary parts.  Did you mean to interleave these?

Comment: the differential equations are: dA(t)/dt= A(t)*C(t)+B(t)*C(t) ; dB(t)/dt= B(t)*C(t) and dC(t)/dt= C(t) . Each element (both real and imaginary parts of each element) of any matrix is a function of t.

Comment: BTW, the code I presented works for me perfectly, except for the 2 questions I  mentioned.

Comment: I understand the eqns; my question is about how the real and imag. values in `A`, `B` and `C` are stored in `x`.  When you unpack `x` at the start of `system(x,t)`, it is clear that, for example, `x[1]` is the imag. part of `A[0,0]`. So the second element of the list returned by `system(x,t)` should be the time derivative of imaginary part of `A[0,0]`.  That is, it should be `dA_dt[0,0].imag`. You return `list_A_real + ...`, which means you are returning `list_A_real[1]` as the time derivative of the imaginary part of `A[0,0]`. But `list_A_real[1]` is `dA_dt[0,1].real`, not `dA_dt[0,0].imag`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser , I see! so your point is I am not maintaining the order correctly while returning the result of the ODE. But what if I define my new/returning "A matrix" as A= matrix([ [x[:,0]+1j*x[:,4],x[:,1]+1j*x[:,5]],[x[:,2]+1j*x[:,6],x[:,3]+1j*x[:,7]] ]) ? Does it do the job, or I have to stick to my first assignment order?

Comment: Yes, that was the point of my question.  Suppose you call the return value `dxdt`.  You can adopt whatever convention you like for assigning components of `A`, `B` and `C` to `x`, but you must use the same convention for assigning the time derivatives of those components to `dxdt`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser , good to know that, let me edit my question to fix the issue you pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier this year I created a wrapper for `scipy.integrate.odeint` that makes it easy to solve complex array differential equations: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw

You can check out the whole package using git and install it using the script `setup.py`, or you can grab the one essential file, [`_odeintw.py`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw/blob/master/odeintw/_odeintw.py), rename it to `odeintw.py`, and copy it to wherever you need it.  The following script uses the function `odeintw.odeintw` to solve your system.  It uses `odeintw` by stacking your three matrices `A`, `B` and `C` into a three-dimensional array `M` with shape (3, 2, 2).

You can use `numpy.linalg.eigvals` to compute the eigenvalues of `A(t)`.  The script shows an example and a plot.  The eigenvalues are complex, so you might have to experiment a bit to find a nice way to visualize them.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linspace, array
from odeintw import odeintw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def system(M, t):
    A, B, C = M
    dA_dt = A.dot(C) + B.dot(C)
    dB_dt = B.dot(C)
    dC_dt = C
    return array([dA_dt, dB_dt, dC_dt])


t = np.linspace(0, 1.5, 1000)

#A_initial= [1, 2, 2.3, 4.3, 2.1, 5.2, 2.13, 3.43]
A_initial = np.array([[1 + 2.1j, 2 + 5.2j], [2.3 + 2.13j, 4.3 + 3.43j]])

# B_initial= [7, 2.7, 1.23, 3.3, 3.1, 5.12, 1.13, 3]
B_initial = np.array([[7 + 3.1j, 2.7 + 5.12j], [1.23 + 1.13j, 3.3 + 3j]])

# C_initial= [0.5, 0.9, 0.63, 0.43, 0.21, 0.5, 0.11, 0.3]
C_initial = np.array([[0.5 + 0.21j, 0.9 + 0.5j], [0.63 + 0.11j, 0.43 + 0.3j]])

M_initial = np.array([A_initial, B_initial, C_initial])
sol = odeintw(system, M_initial, t)

A = sol[:, 0, :, :]
B = sol[:, 1, :, :]
C = sol[:, 2, :, :]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t, A[:, 0, 0].real, label='A(t)[0,0].real')
plt.plot(t, A[:, 0, 0].imag, label='A(t)[0,0].imag')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('t')

A_evals = np.linalg.eigvals(A)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t, A_evals[:,0].real, 'b.', markersize=3, mec='b')
plt.plot(t, A_evals[:,0].imag, 'r.', markersize=3, mec='r')
plt.plot(t, A_evals[:,1].real, 'b.', markersize=3, mec='b')
plt.plot(t, A_evals[:,1].imag, 'r.', markersize=3, mec='r')
plt.ylim(-200, 1200)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Real and imaginary parts of the eigenvalues of A(t)')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.show()
```

Here are the plots generated by the script:

[image: <code>A[0,0]</code>]

[image: eigenvalues of A]

Comment: I copied the file and named it odeintw.py to the same folder. Now when I run the code above that you wrote down, I am getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.....", line 27, in <module>
    sol = odeintw(system, M_initial, t)
  File "/home/...../odeintw.py", line 180, in odeintw
    y0 = y0.astype(np.complex128, copy=False)
TypeError: astype() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: What version of numpy are you using?  I guess the `copy` argument of the `astype` method was added in a later version of numpy.  You can remove that argument from the call of `astype(...)`, and the code should still work fine.  There are two calls to `astype` in the file--change them both.  (I'll put "make odeintw more tolerant of older versions of numpy" on my to-do list. :)

Comment: The `copy` argument of `astype` was added in numpy 1.7.

Comment: @string: I updated the file `_odeintw.py` on github to handle pre-1.7 numpy.  It worked for me with numpy 1.6.2.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work,but unfortunately now I am getting another error.My numpy version is 1.6.1 and now I am using your updated _odeint.w package. The error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name.py", line 40, in <module>
    A_evals = np.linalg.eigvals(A)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 765, in eigvals
    _assertRank2(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 155, in _assertRank2
    two-dimensional' % len(a.shape)
LinAlgError: 3-dimensional array given. Array must be             two-dimensional

Comment: Never mind, all these errors are due to old numpy version,I just upgraded to 1.9.0 version and everything runs smoothly. Thank you so much for your suggestions,I appreciate that.I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the generalized behavior of `np.linalg.eigvals` is also a relatively new feature of numpy.  Upgrading makes sense; I'm glad to hear it is working.