# Solve ode in python with complex matrix as initial value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, quantum-computing

I have a von Neumann equation which looks like:
*dr/dt = - i [H, r]*, where r and H are square matricies of complex numbers and I need to find r(t) using python script.

***Is there any standart instruments to integrate such equations?***

When I was solving another aquation with a vector as initial value, like Schrodinger equation:
*dy/dt = - i H y*, I used scipy.integrate.ode function ('zvode'), but trying to use the same function for von Neumann equation gives me the following error:

```
**scipy/integrate/_ode.py:869: UserWarning: zvode: Illegal input detected. (See printed message.)
ZVODE--  ZWORK length needed, LENZW (=I1), exceeds LZW (=I2)
self.messages.get(istate, 'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
  In above message,  I1 =        72   I2 =        24**
```

Here is the code:

```
def integrate(r, t0, t1, dt):
  e = linspace(t0, t1, (t1 - t0) / dt + 10)
  g = linspace(t0, t1, (t1 - t0) / dt + 10)
  u = linspace(t0, t1, (t1 - t0) / dt + 10)
  while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    r.integrate(r.t + dt)
    e[r.t / dt] = abs(r.y[0][0]) ** 2
    g[r.t / dt] = abs(r.y[1][1]) ** 2
    u[r.t / dt] = abs(r.y[2][2]) ** 2
  return e, g, u


# von Neumann equation's
def right_part(t, rho):
  hamiltonian = (h / 2) * array(
    [[delta, omega_s, omega_p / 2.0 * sin(t * w_p)],
    [omega_s, 0.0, 0.0],
    [omega_p / 2.0 * sin(t * w_p), 0.0, 0.0]],
    dtype=complex128)
  return (dot(hamiltonian, rho) - dot(rho, hamiltonian)) / (1j * h)


def create_integrator():
  r = ode(right_part).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf', with_jacobian=False)
  psi_init = array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=complex128)
  t0 = 0
  r.set_initial_value(psi_init, t0)
  return r, t0


def main():
  r, t0 = create_integrator()
  t1 = 10 ** -6
  dt = 10 ** -11
  e, g, u = integrate(r, t0, t1, dt)

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a wrapper of [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) called [`odeintw`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw) that can handle complex matrix equations such as this.  See [How to plot the Eigenvalues when solving matrix coupled differential equations in PYTHON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580854/how-to-plot-the-eigenvalues-when-solving-matrix-coupled-differential-equations-i/26582411#26582411) for another question involving a matrix differential equation.

Here's a simplified version of your code that shows how you could use it.  (For simplicity, I got rid of most of the constants from your example).

```
import numpy as np
from odeintw import odeintw


def right_part(rho, t, w_p):
    hamiltonian = (1. / 2) * np.array(
        [[0.1, 0.01, 1.0 / 2.0 * np.sin(t * w_p)],
        [0.01, 0.0, 0.0],
        [1.0 / 2.0 * np.sin(t * w_p), 0.0, 0.0]],
        dtype=np.complex128)
    return (np.dot(hamiltonian, rho) - np.dot(rho, hamiltonian)) / (1j)


psi_init = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=np.complex128)


t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
sol = odeintw(right_part, psi_init, t, args=(0.25,))
```

`sol` will be a complex numpy array with shape `(101, 3, 3)`, holding the solution `rho(t)`.  The first index is the time index, and the other two indices are the 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

[QuTiP](http://qutip.googlecode.com/svn/doc/HEAD/html/guide/guide-dynamics.html) has some nice integrators for doing just this, using things like Master equations and Lindblad damping terms. QuTiP itself is only a thin wrapper around scipy.odeint, but it makes a lot of the mechanics much nicer, particularly since it has great documentation.

Comment: Looks like it can replace numpy in terms of tensor operation! Pretty cool!